# I want to check if the user is at a specific location using swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to check if the user is at a specific location , i already have the users location but i can't seem to check if they are at specific coordinates . I have tried to use `.distanceFromLocation` but it doesn't seem to get recognised.

```
let sourceCoorodinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
    let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.5676238, -2.4632888999999523)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific location could be a square for example you have to define it first.

Each point got a latitude and a longitude

( lat-,lon-) ☐---☐ (lat+, lon-)

(lat-,lon+) ☐---☐ (lat+, lon+)

then you just have to check if your location is inside?

```
if (location.latitude > lat- && location.latitude < lat+ && 
location.longitude > lon- && location.longitude < lon+)
{
   //I'm inside the square location
   //Do Stuff
}
```

This example work just with perfect square which coincides with the latitude & longitude lines of the earth

Hope it help, see you

Comment: Thank you, this is great

Comment: your Welcome, don't forget to mark correct answer or add some review on your question to get more answer. Peace